# I installed Node-12 from source but can't get nodejs --version

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, version

I have a problem after installing node in Ubuntu 16. I installed node-12 from **node-v12.13.1-linux-x64.tar.xz** but I can't get `nodejs --version` to execute.

```
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing
sudo apt install nodejs
```

What should I do ?

---

[image: image-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do `node -v` , nodejs is not the name of the executable

Comment: I want to install nodejs. so, node is nodeje , is right ?

Comment: Yes. Nodejs's cli tool is `node`